Anime in which the main character goes on a search for his missing father with a ring or necklace that his father left for him
I'm trying to identify an anime I saw as a kid, even before I knew any difference between an anime or a cartoon. But I definitely know now that it's an anime.
The the main character goes on a search for his missing father with a ring or necklace that his father left for him. He figures out that when he is in danger, a huge robotic or mystic warrior come out from it and fights for him and goes back.
On the journey, he realises there is a total organisation that uses and collects these type of powerful rings and necklaces and a good side and bad side. As the journey goes, the hero starts collecting more powerful rings and also meets a master that helps him train.
There's a key word that I vaguely remember: omletix or amletix or amnetrox; something like that.

In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was this a movie or a series? And can you describe the appearance of any of the characters?

It would also be helpful if you could name any anime you know of with similar themes that aren't the one you're looking for.

"omletix or amletix or amnetrox" reminde me of the omnitrix in  the Ben 10 francise.
